# XeTeX - \glt or \trans don't work in gb4e

Tags: xetex, packages, gb4e

I have a quite big xetex file in which I wrote some examples with gloses and translations. The compilation fails, though it works on a small test file. I think there must be a conflict between packages but I don't see where. Here is my code (not very neat, apologies). Thank you for any help, suggestion...

Here is the code that does not work, I put all the packages declared in the preamble. I tried to move some to resolve the conflicts but nothing worked in this case :

```
    \documentclass[color,a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{theseinalco}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{sectsty}    
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
%%% Footnote rule %%%
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm} \setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\\vspace*{0.101cm}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{11pt}
\usepackage {imakeidx}  
    \makeindex[columns=3,intoc]
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nopostdot, shortcuts]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
    \makeglossaries
    \loadglsentries{glossaire-these}    
    \loadglsentries{gloses-abrv}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{labelwidth=2em, labelsep=.5em, font=\normalfont}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\newcounter {subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection .\@arabic\c@subsubsubsection}
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{10.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*{\subsubsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}\frenchspacing
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=Common,Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={WordSpace=2,LetterSpace=8F}]{Latin Modern Roman}

\setotherlanguages{hindi,urdu}
    \newfontfamily\hindifont[Script=Devanagari,Language=Hindi,Mapping=tex-text]{Lohit Devanagari}    
    \newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Mapping=tex-text]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
    \usepackage{gb4e,cgloss4e}
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,breaklinks=true}
        \begin{exe}\ex
    \gll This sentence is an example\\
         ceci phrase est un exemple\\
    \glt Cette phrase est un exemple.
        \end{exe}   
\end{document}
```

The package 'theseinalco' is specific to my institute, the code is here : https://bitbucket.org/tpellard/theseinalco/src/master/ (it's a bit long to be displayed here).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When I run your example code I don't get any errors. The only things that I've changed are to remove the `\loadglsentries` lines because I don't have the files with your entries and change the Devanagari and Arabic fonts to Noto Serif and Amiri because I didn't have your fonts. Both of these issues are unlikely to influence `gb4e` though. Do you get any warnings or error messages?